# Chrome [Version 87.0.4280.88] won't open - Jan 2021. Does anyone know the download to fix this?

Tags: google-chrome

Version 87.0.4280.88 (Official Build) (64-bit) - Jan 2021 latest

Chrome works great at first until I start my Angular application, and create a new PDF File.  Subsequent attempts to open Chrome through my shortcut on Desktop or Task Bar shows it trying to do something, but nothing shows.

I was able to track it down to what I thought was my Virus software (WebRoot) because, when I disabled it, this problem vanished. That seemed odd and a possible WebRoot bug, but in fact as I read more about these kinds of issues, I found that Chrome is affected by file locks being put onto the new file by WebRoot so that it can (later) run a scan and then releasing that lock.

I proved that this is the root cause, by simply deleting newly created files using file explorer. After doing that, the browser worked flawlessly.

**Symptoms**

Open up task manager and you will see many instances of 'Google Chrome' running.

**Chrome acknowledges this bug and is working on a fix**

> [Google Chrome has fixed a bug that enabled antivirus programs](https://www.google.com/search?q=Google%20Chrome%20has%20fixed%20a%20bug%20that%20enabled%20antivirus%20programs) on Windows 10 to lock newly created files. The patching of the bug means antivirus programs running on Windows would no longer block new files generated by the Chrome web browser, such as bookmarks.

Chrome is set to auto-update.  But the current version download 87.0.4280.88 does not work.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The fix was to install the latest version of Chrome. Which is Version 88.0.4324.150 (Official Build) (64-bit)

Note: Microsoft Edge opens much faster than Chrome does now.

Answer (score 0):

**Work Around**

- First try to run your antivirus, the idea being it will unlock the file.
- If that doesn't work, delete any newly created files using file explorer, this should immediately allow for new instances.
- You may also try to click on the Magnifying Glass and then from  Top Apps area, click Google Chrome there, not sure why this works.

*Clean up hung Instances*

- Use 'Exit', by clicking on the three dots '...' in upper right hand corner of any visible Chrome instance. This will get rid of all Chrome tasks.

Here's a PowerShell script that stops all chrome instances.

```
if (!([Security.Principal.WindowsPrincipal][Security.Principal.WindowsIdentity]::GetCurrent()).IsInRole([Security.Principal.WindowsBuiltInRole]::Administrator)) {
    Start-Process PowerShell -Verb RunAs "-NoProfile -ExecutionPolicy Bypass -Command `"cd '$pwd'; & '$PSCommandPath';`"";
    exit;
}
Stop-Process -Name chrome
Stop-Process -Name GoogleCrashHandler 
Stop-Process -Name GoogleCrashHandler64
```

Note: rebooting you computer works too, but not recommended because problem will come back forcing frequent time consuming reboots.

**Bug fix**

Not out yet, but will be one subsequent to Version 87.0.4280.88